# Gridview Alternative to php?

Tags: php

I have a table called "contact" which has unique contacts in it. I have another table called "message" which has multiple rows for each contact.

I want to create a web interface where the contacts show up as rows and it would have a plus sign or expand sign on the left of it, and after clicking that I want the rows in the message table related to that contact to expand.

Are there any open source projects which make doing this easy so I don't have to write all the code from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`dataTable`](http://www.datatables.net/) jQuery plugin.

[Here is an Example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html)